# Flex 4.6 TabbedViewNavigatorApplication navigator

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.6

I am new to mobile development with Flex, and there is one basic piece of information with which I cannot find an answer.

My main application extends the `<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>` class. With other application classes, such as `<s:ViewNavigatorApplication>`, I can do the following to transition between `<s:View>` components:

```
private function nextView(e:MouseEvent):void {
    navigator.pushView(package.component);
}
```

However, the `<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>` does not automatically instantiate `navigator` as do the other base classes.

Could someone please provide a simple example of how to push and pop views from a `<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TabbedViewNavigatorApplication contains one ViewNavigator per tab, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

<s:navigators>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="News" firstView="views.NewsView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Friends" firstView="views.FriendsView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Events" firstView="views.EventsView"/>
</s:navigators>
```

Each ViewNavigator maintains its own navigation stack. The ViewNavigator methods pushView() and popView() act on the currently selected ViewNavigator. These methods add/remove from the selected tab's stack, not the TabbedViewNavigatorApplication.

Similarly, the back button navigates within the stack of a single tab. It doesn't select another tab.

You can navigate *between* ViewNavigators(i.e. between tabs) by setting the TabbedViewNavigator.selectedIndex property to the index of the desired ViewNavigator, where 0 is the first section(first tab), 1 is the second, etc. For example:

```
TabbedViewNavigator.selectedIndex = 2
```

selects the third tab (and third ViewNavigator stack).

You can read more about TabbedViewNavigatorApplication on the [Adobe Help pages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS77c1dbb1bd80d383527e1a6412a8a5d909a-8000.html).